# Bluetooth no longer works after system update

Tags: release-loki, updates, bluetooth

I've been using elementaryOS Loki for a while but after I decided to update packages queued in my System Updates, Bluetooth, along with its icon in Wingpanel ceased to work, although I'm not entirely sure if that was the cause.

`rfkill list` output

```
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

After running `bluetooth-wizard` the program can't seem to find my Wireless Headphones that were working fine up to yesterday, it's just stuck in `Searching for devices...`. Enlarging the window to properly show the device list didn't change anything, no devices appeared.

Reinstalling the package `bluez` did not work.

Any help with this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am also using Lenovo Ideapad. Had the same issue.
Turn ON bluetooth from panel, open Terminal and copy-paste this:

`rfkill unblock bluetooth`

see if this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

yes its work but the discover list is so small and you can't see the devices but you can make scroll and select one, then you have to change the channel in sound settings and then you have to change the mode (maybe), sorry for my English but i hope help you